# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2. How can this be fixed?

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

**I am building a static ListView. How can I solve this error? Also how can I add a UI to the ListView?**

Following is my class MatchData code:

```
class MatchData {
  String date, team1, team2, time;

  MatchData({@required this.date, @required this.team1, @required this.team2, @required this.time});
}
```

Following is the Data I want to show in the ListView:

```
final List<MatchData> dayMatch = [
    MatchData(
        date: '12/02/2020',
        team1: 'Mumbai Indians',
        team2: 'Bangalore',
        time: '16:00'),
    MatchData(
        date: '12/02/2020',
        team1: 'Mumbai Indians',
        team2: 'Bangalore',
        time: '16:00')
  ];

  match() {
    return dayMatch;
  }
```

Following is the body of my Widget:

```
body: Center(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                  Text(dayMatch[index].date),
                  Text(dayMatch[index].team1),
                  Text(dayMatch[index].time),
                  Text(dayMatch[index].team2),
                ],
            ),
          );
        }
```

Comment: Please how did you solve the issue? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I added itemCount

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `itemCount` and the screen is big enough to display ten items, `ListView.builder()` builds a little more than ten children, and even more on demand if you scroll down.

In your case, `ListView.builder()` tries to build more than two children, while your list (dayMatch) only has two elements, which is why the error occurs.

To fix it, just pass the number of items to the `itemCount` argument, or it'll be somewhat better to use the [default constructor of ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html) instead if the number is fixed and small. `ListView.builder()` does more computing under the hood to be flexible, which is a little too much for a small list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "itemCount".

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: dayMatch.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(dayMatch[index].date),
          Text(dayMatch[index].team1),
          Text(dayMatch[index].time),
          Text(dayMatch[index].team2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
),
```